# How to access printers configured on windows-print-server using java?

Tags: java, printing, java-print

I have one windows-print-server(ip 192.168.2.1) configured with all the printers in my network. 
I have a java(spring boot) application which runs on another windows box(ip 192.168.2.2) in the same network. 
Need to add printing capabilities in the application but to start with I have some basic queries

- How to access/connect windows-print-server from the java application to get the list of all the printers.
- How to send a print job to a specific printer?

Will appreciate if you can help me with some pointers/libraries or sample code. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend taking a look at PDFbox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523583/sending-data-to-a-printer-in-java

Comment: Appreciate your response. but my requirement is little diff. My java application and windows-print-server are running on two diff machines. Hence the code "PrintService printServiceObj = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();" does not get the printers I am looking for.